# MySQL кодировка

Tags: mysql, база-данных, кодировка, utf-8

Как установить кодировку UTF-8?
Что не пробовал всегда остается latin1.

```
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                                   |
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                                                 |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                                                 |
| character_set_database   | latin1                                                  |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                                  |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                                                 |
| character_set_server     | latin1                                                  |
| character_set_system     | utf8
```

Файл my.ini

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
port=3306

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysqld]
init_connect=‘SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_unicode_ci’
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Посоветуйте что-то)

Comment: Похожий вопрос в [англоязычной ветке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253039/cant-change-charset-in-mysql-5-7-from-latin-to-utf8). Вот [ещё](http://gahcep.github.io/blog/2013/01/05/mysql-utf8/).

Comment: @Rootware, спасибо. Уже сам нашел)

Comment: Ну так оформите ответ на свой вопрос. Возможно кому-то пригодится готовое решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение:

Файл my.ini

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8
port=3306

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

И после обязательно перезагрузите MySQL.

Пример на Windows:

Открываем консоль и прописываем:

```
net stop MySQL 
net start MySQL
```